# How do you send selected data back from modal popup to parent form and close modal

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, modal-dialog

I have in my parent form the following code which opens a modal list view of items.

```
<?php
    // My Stuff
    $field = $fieldSet['jform_my_stuff'];
    ?>
    <div class="control-group <?php echo 'field-' . $field->id . $field->responsive; ?>">
        <div class="control-label">
            <?php echo $field->label; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $field->input; ?>
        <?php
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
?>
<a class="modal"
<a href="index.php?option=com_popuptry&amp;view=stuff&amp;layout=stuff&amp;tmpl=component" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 600}}">Select</a>
        </div>
```

The form looks like this.

[image: Parent Page]

The feild I want the data to be updated to is

jform_my_stuff

I have tried a number of options but just cannot get the modal to send back the required input

I replaced all my efforts with some txt for now

[image: Modal]

The last peice of code would go in here

```
</td>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <td style="text-align:center">
                <?php echo JDom::_('html.fly', array(
                    'dataKey' => 'stuff',
                    'dataObject' => $row
                ));?>


            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
            Button here to send selected item (stuff) <br>back to parent feild called jform_my_stuff<br> & close modal
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $k = 1 - $k;
    endfor;
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am completely lost as to what I need to put in here as most things have not worked.. ?? any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Javascript. (I use jquery here). I'm doing my best to understand what you are trying to do.

Basically, I'd write a function to handle the button click.

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="sendToMyStuff()">
```

The function would be as follows:

```
function sendToMyStuff(){
    var stuff = $('input[name="checkbox"]:checked').val(); // "stuff"
    $('#mystuff').val(stuff); //Sent the value of the stuff input -- if it is not an input you can use .text()
    $('#modal').hide(); //Hide the modal window
}
```

You could also simply use the ID of the checkbox to get the data. I wasn't exactly sure what you are trying to do. I am also not super familiar with Joomla. You could also just bind the button click.

```
$('#button').bind('click', function(){ }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, tried that in the modal form but it only showed the button and did nothing else. I believe it needs to take the data from $row.stuff and place it in a field on the parent form called jform_my_stuff and then close the modal..

Comment: That's what it should do. Are you able to retrieve that value from the checkbox? Have you tried printing/logging the data to make sure it is being retrieved properly?

Comment: I'm sorry Im an absolute beginer when it comes to code. Appreciate you trying to help me.. Im not even sure how to check if the data is being retrieved properly. :(

The list view of items would have a button on each row - on click it would take the row from $row and data held in stuff so $row.stuff. The check box would be irrelevant for the transfer. Send the data to jform_my_stuff on the parent page and close. I think I understand what the Jscript is doing but still cannot get it to work - the button doesn't even close the modal which I am sure it should do.

Comment: Doesn't the checkbox tell you which row of data you are transferring?